# Trial division for primes with immutable collections in Scala

Tags: algorithm, scala, data-structures, functional-programming

I am trying to learn Scala and functional programming ideology by rewriting basic exercises. Currently I have trouble with naive approach for generating primes "trial division".

**The trouble described below is that I could not rewrite well-known algorithm in functional style preserving efficiency, because I have no suitable immutable data structure, like a List but with fast operations not only on head, but also on the very end.**

I started with writing java code which for every odd number tests its divisibility by already found primes (limited by square root of value being tested) - and adds it to the end of the list if no divisor was found.

http://ideone.com/QE8U0I

```
    List<Integer> primes = new ArrayList<>();
    primes.add(2);
    int cur = 3;
    while (primes.size() < 100000) {
        for (Integer x : primes) {
            if (x * x > cur) {
                primes.add(cur);
                break;
            }
            if (cur % x == 0) {
                break;
            }
        }
        cur += 2;
    }
```

Now I tried to rewrite it in "functional way" - there was no problem with using recursion instead of loops, but I stuck with immutable collections. Core idea is as following:

http://ideone.com/4DQ6mi

```
def primes(n: Int) = {
    @tailrec
    def divisibleByAny(x: Int, list: List[Int]): Boolean = {
        if (list.isEmpty) false else {
            val h = list.head
            h * h <= x && (x % h == 0 || divisibleByAny(x, list.tail))
        }
    }
    @tailrec
    def morePrimes(from: Int, prev: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
        if (prev.size == n) prev else
            morePrimes(from + 2, if (divisibleByAny(from, prev)) prev else prev :+ from)
    }
    morePrimes(3, List(2))
}
```

But it is **slow** - if I understand correctly because operation of **adding to the end of immutable list** requires creation of new copy of the whole stuff.

I searched over documentation to find more suitable data structure and tried to substitute list with immutable Queue, for it is said:

> Adding items to the queue always has cost O(1) ... Removing an item is on average O(1).

But it is still even slower:

http://ideone.com/v8BsuQ

```
def primes(n: Int) = {
    @tailrec
    def divisibleByAny(x: Int, list: Queue[Int]): Boolean = {
        if (list.isEmpty) false else {
            val (h, t) = list.dequeue
            h * h <= x && (x % h == 0 || divisibleByAny(x, t))
        }
    }
    @tailrec
    def morePrimes(from: Int, prev: Queue[Int]): Queue[Int] = {
        if (prev.size == n) prev else
            morePrimes(from + 2, if (divisibleByAny(from, prev)) prev else prev.enqueue(from))
    }
    morePrimes(3, Queue(2))
}
```

What is going wrong or am I missing something?

P.S. I believe there are other algorithms for generating primes which are more suitable for functional style. I think I've seen some paper. But now I'm interested in this one, or more precisely in existence of suitable data structure.

Comment: `Vector`s have (amortised) cost O(1) for adding, removing (from both ends) and retrieval. Aside from that, adding to the beginning of the list is O(1) so why not do just that?

Comment: Never mind, I see why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html `Vector`s have an amortised constant cost for appending, prepending and seeking. Indeed, using vectors instead of lists in your solution is much faster

```
def primes(n: Int) = {
  @tailrec
  def divisibleByAny(x: Int, list: Vector[Int]): Boolean = {
    if (list.isEmpty) false else {
      val (h +: t) = list
      h * h <= x && (x % h == 0 || divisibleByAny(x, t))
    }
  }
  @tailrec
  def morePrimes(from: Int, prev: Vector[Int]): Vector[Int] = {
    if (prev.length == n) prev else
      morePrimes(from + 2, if (divisibleByAny(from, prev)) prev else prev :+ from)
  }
  morePrimes(3, Vector(2))
}
```

http://ideone.com/x3k4A3

Comment: Thank you, I've tried and it looks exactly as what I was looking for. It seems I had mistaken Vector for similarly named java class when I browsed this comparison table before. I'm happy now!

Answer (score 2):

I think you have 2 main options

1. Use a Vector - which is better than a list for appending.  It is a Bitmapped Trie data structure (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie). It’s “effectively” O(1) for appending to (i.e. O(1) on average)

Or...possibly the answer you're not looking for

2. Use a mutable data structure like ListBuffer - immutability it great to try achieve, and should be your go to collections - but sometimes for efficiency reasons, you may use mutable structures .  What is key it to make sure it does not “leak out” of your classes.  If you look at the List.scala implementation, you’ll see ListBuffer used a lot internally.  However, its coverted back to a List just before it leaves the class.  If its good enough for the core Scala libraries, its probably ok for you to use under exceptional cases that warrant it.

Answer (score 1):

Except using `Vector`, also consider using higher-order functions instead of recursion. That's also a completely valid functional style. On my machine the following implementation of `divisibleByAny` is about 8x faster, than @Pyetras tailrec implementation when running `primes(1000000)`:

```
def divisibleByAny(x: Int, list: Vector[Int]): Boolean =
  list.view.takeWhile(el => el * el <= x).exists(x % _ == 0)
```